# How do I sync up my discord bot's task loop with the system time or a time zone in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to sync up my bot_test_clear function with my system time or a time zone for example, it is 1:00pm and the function runs after 1 hour it is 2:00pm and the function runs agane regardless of when I ran the script it should run every hour even if i stoped the script at 1:30pm the time should not reset like how it does with the task loop timer.

Here is the code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands,tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', help_command=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, 
  activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name='!help'))
  bot_test_clear.start()
  print(f"{client.user} is online")

@tasks.loop(hours=1)
  async def bot_test_clear():
  channel_bot_test = client.get_channel("channel id")
  messages = await channel_bot_test.history(limit=123).flatten()

  if not messages:
    return
  else:
    embed = discord.Embed(description='It has been 1 hour, clearing chats...', color=system_color)
    await channel_bot_test.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await channel_bot_test.purge(limit=None) 

client.run('token')
```

with the script above if I start it at 1:35pm it will run agane at 2:35, I dont want that.
pls, help.

Note:
1)this script clears all messages in a discord channel after a hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the delta to the nearest hour and sleep for that amount of seconds in `before_loop`

```py
from datetime import datetime

@tasks.loop(hours=1)
async def bot_test_clear():
    channel_bot_test = client.get_channel("channel id")
    messages = await channel_bot_test.history(limit=123).flatten()

    if not messages:
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(description='It has been 1 hour, clearing chats...', color=system_color)
    await channel_bot_test.send(embed=embed)

    # I'd create an asyncio.Task for this since it can take a bit of time to complete
    # and it will delay the next iteration of the loop
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await channel_bot_test.purge(limit=None) 


@bot_test_clear.before_loop
async def before():
    now = datetime.now()  # or `utcnow`
    future = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour + 1, 0)
    delta = (future - now).total_seconds()

    await asyncio.sleep(delta)


bot_test_clear.start()
```

Comment: ok, I have question. so at task.loop(hours=1) when we run the script it calls to the before function so will it call to the before function every time and how does the .before_loop work give a link or something. thanks btw.

Comment: No, `before_loop` is only called once, before starting the actual loop